# How to use emacs in msys2 with gui

Tags: windows, emacs, msys2

I installed emacs with msys2, and find it pretty fast when compared with cygwin's. But the only problem is I cannot find a way to start its GUI. I have installed Xming, a Xwindows server, and can use Gimp, Inkscape. But why there is no GUI starter for emacs?

Comment: I have an msys2 install and Emacs pops up a GUI by default.  The package name is `mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs`.  It doesn't look like I have an X server in msys2; I assume it's using the Windows toolkit for GUI stuff.

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me. You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @jpkotta do you know if it's possible to start `mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs` without first opening a MinGW shell? Ex: make it the default to open certain files.

Comment: @bobpaul Not sure.  If you just run `emacs.exe` it seems to always open a console window in the background.  I vaguely remember an `emacsw.exe` that used to come with some windows version of Emacs, and I think the point of that was to start without a console.

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed more than one binary for emacs under MSYS2:  Try looking at the result of

```
% which emacs
```

The gui version is in /mingw64/bin, and the non-gui version is under /usr/bin.  If you don't see the version in /mingw64/bin, then likely you need to add the emacs package:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, Emacs GUI is run with `runemacs.exe`.

If one uses the default installation path, Emacs' GUI will be:  `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\runemacs.exe`.